# How to trace abnormal termination in pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have a pl sql file which process around 7000 records. Based on input it does select insert ,update to different table. Exception handler is written in each query. But my program terminates abnormally without displaying any error message. And this termination happens at different places of code at each time. First time it may process 1200 records, next time it process 1400. Is it related to cache issue? Please provide the input to resolve this issue. I am using sql developer 1.5.4. Is there any way to debug such scenario?

Adding Pl sql file:

Below is my pl sql file and which reads the input from 'marx_resph_bk.txt' as mentioned in file.

=================================================================================

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

exec dbms_output.enable(NULL);

declare

  v_line         varchar2(500);
  v_cnt          integer;
  v_cntp          integer:=0;
  v_cnth          integer:=0;
  v_file_date    date := to_date('20140201','yyyymmdd');
  v_avail_date   date := to_date('20131210','yyyymmdd');
  v_sent_date    date;
  v_eff_date     date;
  v_status       char;
  ACCEPTED       char := 'A';
  REJECTED       char := 'R';

  v_tracking_id  kc.kc_marx_transaction.kmt_marx_tsa_sk%type;
  v_hicn  kc.kc_marx_transaction.kmt_hicn_id%type;
  v_c_id         kc.kc_marx_transaction.c_id%type;
  v_trcs         kc.kc_marx_transaction.kmt_tsa_rpy_cd%type;
  v_disp_cd      kc.kc_marx_transaction.kmt_disp_cd%type;
  v_pl_id        kc.kc_hcfa_mbr_transaction.pl_id%type;
  v_cms_ttc      kc.kc_hcfa_mbr_transaction.kcmt_type_code%type;
  v_ic_ttc       kc.kc_hcfa_mbr_transaction.kcmt_type_code%type;
  v_td_id        kc.kc_validations.td_id%type;
  v_qd_id        kc.kc_validations.qd_id%type;


  f_verbatim utl_file.file_type;
  f_errors   utl_file.file_type;

  cursor c_Trcs is
    select kcmt_reply_code trc
    from kc.kc_hcfa_mbr_transaction
    where c_id = v_c_id
    and pl_id = v_pl_id
    and kcmt_file_date = v_file_date
    and kcmt_cms_aval_dt = v_avail_date
    and kcmt_type_code = v_cms_ttc;

begin
utl_file.fclose(f_verbatim);
  utl_file.fclose(f_errors);
  f_verbatim := utl_file.fopen ('/net/iRX_downloads2/work/infocare_utl', 'marx_resph_bk.txt', 'r');
  f_errors   := utl_file.fopen('/net/iRX_downloads2/work/infocare_utl', 'marx_result.txt', 'w');
<<next_hic>>
  loop
    begin

      utl_file.get_line(f_verbatim, v_line);
      v_cntp := v_cntp+1;
      dbms_output.put_line(' Line CNT: '||v_cntp);
      exception
        when no_data_found then
        dbms_output.put_line(' No Line');
          exit;
    end;

    v_hicn := substr(v_line,1,10);
    v_status := substr(v_line,474,1);
    v_tracking_id := to_number(substr(v_line,486,15));

    begin
      dbms_output.put_line(' Selecting marx_transaction');
      select c_id, substr(kmt_ctc_id,2,4), kmt_tsa_cd, kmt_eff_dt,
        kmt_snt_to_marx_sys_dt, nvl(kmt_disp_cd,'X')
      into v_c_id, v_pl_id, v_ic_ttc, v_eff_date, v_sent_date, v_disp_cd
      from kc.kc_marx_transaction
      where kmt_marx_tsa_sk = v_tracking_id;

      if v_disp_cd <> 'X' then
        dbms_output.put_line(' Skipping');
        goto next_hic;
      end if;

      exception
        when others then
        dbms_output.put_line(' Selecting tracking Id');
          utl_file.putf(f_errors, 'Select Tracking ID :'||v_tracking_id
            ||':'||sqlerrm);
          rollback;
          return;
    end;

    if v_pl_id = '3909' then
      v_pl_id := '3963';
    end if;

    v_cms_ttc := v_ic_ttc;
    v_td_id := null;
    v_qd_id := null;
    case
      when v_ic_ttc = '51' then
v_td_id := '50'; v_qd_id := '85';
      when v_ic_ttc = '61' then
        v_td_id := '10'; v_qd_id := '20';
      when v_ic_ttc = '71' then
        v_td_id := '90'; v_qd_id := '140'; v_cms_ttc := '61';
      when v_ic_ttc = '73' then
        v_td_id := '73'; v_qd_id := '445';
      when v_ic_ttc = '75' then
        v_td_id := '72'; v_qd_id := '430';
      when v_ic_ttc in ('72','76','78','80','81') then
        null;
      else
        utl_file.putf(f_errors, 'Invalid TTC:'||v_ic_ttc||':Tracking ID :'
          ||v_tracking_id);
          dbms_output.put_line(' Invalid TTC:');
        goto next_hic;
    end case;

    if v_status = REJECTED then
      begin
        delete kc.kc_validations
        where c_id = v_c_id
        and pl_id = v_pl_id
        and td_id = v_td_id
        and ec_code like 'C%';

        exception
          when others then
            null;
      end;
    end if;

    v_cnt := 0;
    v_trcs := null;

    for l_1 in c_Trcs loop

      v_trcs := v_trcs||l_1.trc;
      v_cnt  := v_cnt + 1;
   dbms_output.put_line(' Inside Cursor loop');
      -- Only need to store validation errors for those TTCs that can be
      -- worked through the browse queue screens in the front end
      if v_status = REJECTED and v_td_id is not null then
        begin
          insert into kc.kc_validations
(c_id, pl_id, td_id, qd_id, ec_code, v_column_db_name, v_update_date)
          values
          (v_c_id, v_pl_id, v_td_id, v_qd_id, 'C'||l_1.trc, ' ', sysdate);

          exception
            when others then
            dbms_output.put_line(' Validation Insert:');
              utl_file.putf(f_errors, 'Validation Insert: c_id :'||v_c_id
                ||': pl_id :'||v_pl_Id||': td_id :'||v_td_id||': '||sqlerrm);
              rollback;
              return;
        end;

        if (l_1.trc = '127' or l_1.trc = '169') and v_ic_ttc = '61' then
          begin
             update kc.kc_customer_coverages_new
             set ccv_prj_eff_date = v_eff_date,
                 ccv_accrete_eff_date = v_sent_date,
                 ccv_ssa_medd_wth_prem_eff_dt = v_eff_date,
                 ccv_lis_eff_dt = v_eff_date,
                 ccv_update_date = sysdate,
                 ccv_update_userid = user,
                 cet_type = '4A'
             where c_id = v_c_id
             and   pl_id = v_pl_id;

             exception
               when others then
               dbms_output.put_line(' Error found CCV');
                 utl_file.putf(f_errors, 'CCV Update:c_id:'||v_c_id||':pl_id:'
                   ||v_pl_id||':eff_dt:'||to_char(v_eff_date,'yyyymmdd')||':'
                   ||'sent_dt:'||to_char(v_sent_date,'yyyymmdd')||':'||sqlerrm);
                 rollback;
                 return;
          end;
        end if;
      end if;

      -- KC.KC_MARX_TRANSACTION.KMT_TSA_RPY_CD is only large enough to
      -- accommodate a string of five TRCs (rarely, if ever, is this needed)
      if v_cnt = 5 then
        exit;
      end if;

    end loop;

begin
v_cnth := v_cnth+1;
dbms_output.put_line(' CNT: '||v_cnth);
dbms_output.put_line('v_status: '||v_status||' v_trcs: '||v_trcs||' v_tracking_id: '||v_tracking_id );
dbms_output.put_line(' v_C_ID: '||v_c_id||' v_hicn: '||v_hicn);
      update kc.kc_marx_transaction
      set kmt_disp_cd = v_status,
          kmt_tsa_rpy_cd = v_trcs,
          kmt_rsp_pcs_by_marx_sys_dt = sysdate,
          last_upd_use_id = user,
          last_upd_ts = sysdate,
          last_upd_pgm_nm = 'ACCRETION II - ACCR_ACC_REJ_STATUS.SQL'
      where kmt_marx_tsa_sk = v_tracking_id;

      exception
        when others then
        dbms_output.put_line(' Error Update Tracking');
          utl_file.putf(f_errors, 'Update Tracking ID :'||v_tracking_id
            ||':'||sqlerrm);
          rollback;
          return;
    end;

  end loop;
 dbms_output.put_line('TOTAL CNT: '||v_cnth);
  utl_file.fclose(f_verbatim);
  utl_file.fclose(f_errors);

commit;
end;
/
```

==============================================================================

And it never reach to a point whereit can display my final   dbms_output.put_line for Total CNT.

Comment: Impossible to answer. You should at least provide your script and sample input. Voted for putting on hold.

Comment: Please show us the stored procedure and how you call it.

Comment: How about giving `EXCEPTION` handling a chance? if that doesn't work come back and ask the question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You exception handler

```
when others then
dbms_output.put_line(' Selecting tracking Id');
  utl_file.putf(f_errors, 'Select Tracking ID :'||v_tracking_id
    ||':'||sqlerrm);
  rollback;
  return;
```

contains error tracking write to file - what about dbms_output.put_line() with the same information ? You could get this as spool file output. Also seems you use loop - end loop; and goto control method - could you use while() looping instead ? It might be more transaparent.

Ald also you have a problem with RETURN statement I guess - because you don't close file handler before return in nested block you don't have information about the error, the file is empty and you don't reach the end of main block:

```
SQL> declare
  2  
  3    f_errors   utl_file.file_type;
  4  
  5  begin
  6    utl_file.fclose(f_errors);
  7    f_errors   := utl_file.fopen('FDC_BTI_DIR', 'test_01.txt', 'w');
  8      begin
  9  
 10        raise no_data_found;
 11  
 12        exception
 13          when others then
 14          dbms_output.put_line(' Selecting tracking Id');
 15            utl_file.putf(f_errors, 'Select Tracking ID :'||sqlerrm);
 16            rollback;
 17            return;
 18      end;
 19    utl_file.fclose(f_errors);
 20  end;
 21  /
Selecting tracking Id                                                           

SQL> declare
  2  
  3    f_errors   utl_file.file_type;
  4    buff varchar2(4000);
  5  
  6  begin
  7    utl_file.fclose(f_errors);
  8    f_errors   := utl_file.fopen('FDC_BTI_DIR', 'test_01.txt', 'r');
  9    utl_file.get_line(f_errors, buff, 4000);
 10    dbms_output.put_line(buff);
 11    utl_file.fclose(f_errors);
 12  end;
 13  /
declare
*
error in line 1:
ORA-01403: data not found 
ORA-06512: at  "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 106 
ORA-06512: at  "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 746 
ORA-06512: at  line 9 


SQL> declare
  2  
  3    f_errors   utl_file.file_type;
  4  
  5  begin
  6    utl_file.fclose(f_errors);
  7    f_errors   := utl_file.fopen('FDC_BTI_DIR', 'test_01.txt', 'w');
  8      begin
  9  
 10        raise too_many_rows;
 11  
 12        exception
 13          when others then
 14          dbms_output.put_line(' Selecting tracking Id');
 15            utl_file.putf(f_errors, 'Select Tracking ID :'||sqlerrm);
 16            utl_file.fclose(f_errors);
 17            rollback;
 18            return;
 19      end;
 20    utl_file.fclose(f_errors);
 21  end;
 22  /
Selecting tracking Id                                                           

SQL> declare
  2  
  3    f_errors   utl_file.file_type;
  4    buff varchar2(4000);
  5  
  6  begin
  7    utl_file.fclose(f_errors);
  8    f_errors   := utl_file.fopen('FDC_BTI_DIR', 'test_01.txt', 'r');
  9    utl_file.get_line(f_errors, buff, 4000);
 10    dbms_output.put_line(buff);
 11    utl_file.fclose(f_errors);
 12  end;
 13  /
Select Tracking ID :ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows                                                                    

SQL> declare
  2  
  3    f_errors   utl_file.file_type;
  4  
  5  begin
  6    utl_file.fclose(f_errors);
  7    f_errors   := utl_file.fopen('FDC_BTI_DIR', 'test_01.txt', 'w');
  8      begin
  9  
 10        raise invalid_number;
 11  
 12        exception
 13          when others then
 14          dbms_output.put_line(' Selecting tracking Id');
 15            utl_file.putf(f_errors, 'Select Tracking ID :'||sqlerrm);
 16            rollback;
 17      end;
 18    utl_file.fclose(f_errors);
 19  end;
 20  /
Selecting tracking Id                                                           

SQL> declare
  2  
  3    f_errors   utl_file.file_type;
  4    buff varchar2(4000);
  5  
  6  begin
  7    utl_file.fclose(f_errors);
  8    f_errors   := utl_file.fopen('FDC_BTI_DIR', 'test_01.txt', 'r');
  9    utl_file.get_line(f_errors, buff, 4000);
 10    dbms_output.put_line(buff);
 11    utl_file.fclose(f_errors);
 12  end;
 13  /
Select Tracking ID :ORA-01722: invalid_number
```